# Copy/paste from the PhD thesis into my future publication

Tags: publications, thesis

I am writing my PhD thesis right now. I do not have any published paper by now, but a manuscript which will be published probably after or at the same time of my defense. Can I just Copy/ Paste some parts (discussion for example) from my manuscript in thesis? Would be any problem afterwards for publishing this manuscript? In other words, I am afraid if the reviewers of paper say that “you cannot Copy and Paste the discussion of your thesis, without rephrasing it”.

Comment: I think this may vary by field and where you do your PhD.  At some places, your thesis can be a bunch of papers stapled together and there are others where your thesis can't be based off things you've already published.

Comment: The point is you want to avoid self-plagiarism, and I think whether your thesis is viewed at the same level of publication depends on culture.

Comment: This definitely isn't a duplicate. The linked question has VERY different constraints (having been published by a separate publisher in a book).

Comment: @Ethan I changed the duplicate target; the new one seems more appropriate. Also see [How much overlap is permitted between a submitted journal article and a thesis?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2281/11365), [Self-Plagiarism in PhD thesis](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12342/11365), [Can I use the work in my journal/conference publications as chapters in my dissertation?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2029/11365), and other related questions.

Answer (score -1):

It is not uncommon to hear about thesis that are based on published papers or drafts of future papers. What I have seen for those thesis is that the author puts a footnote at the beginning of each chapter. The note indicates the journal/conference where the information pertaining to that chapter has been published/presented. You could use this as a guide when writing your thesis.

The most important thing is to make sure that you cite properly everything and that you demonstrate intellectual ownership of the information presented in your thesis.

Comment: However, my Problem is vice versa! I just want to be sure that my paper in the future would not be rejected because it is a copy of a Thesis, without rephrasing!

Comment: This doesn't answer the original poster's question at all, it answers the opposite question :/